# How do I get TFS 2010 to enable Sharepoint portals and reporting?

Tags: tfs, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

Ive tried EVERYTHING. I have installed multiple times combinations of SQL 2008 R2 + Sharepoint 2010 Foundation/Server and VS2010.

Is there something special I need to do to get VS 2010 to realize that there is Sharepoint 2010 + SQL 2008 R2 on my box and to enable reporting and TFS sharepoint portal ?

Maybe the option to enable it is hidden in some menu somewhere.

Any ideas what I can check ?

Comment: Which option did you use installing TFS (e.g Basic, Standard Single Server, Advanced?)  For my sandbox installation, I installed SQL Server, then Standard Single Server on top of that.  Sharepoint and reporting were installed either by default, or I was given an

Comment: I used basic and that didnt worked. So I did advanced. I pointed it at the SQL 2008 R2 instance which has reporting enabled. (When I installed SQL I checked use sharepoint integration during the install wizard) 

I wonder if there is some setting I need to do after default installation of TFS/SQL

Comment: I found this.. I guess this isnt possible on win7 + TFS2010 + SP2010?

Update 4th May 2010

•Nilesh Deshpande from LightSpeedIT in Sydney was asking how he configures SharePoint integration when he has TFS installed on Windows 7. The answer is easy, if not one he will like. You can’t. When you install on Windows 7 you can only do a basic install and the Admin options you would need to configure SharePoint are not available. You will need to move you ProjectCollection to a TFS instance running on a Server OS to be able to do this.